# How to create a suiteapp and deploy it (locked)

Tags: eclipse, ide, netsuite

How can i create a suite app and deploy it from suitecloud IDE (eclipse).I cant find an option to create a suiteapp ,were would i find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding SuiteApps are just Bundles, you don't need SuiteCloud IDE to create one. Although I don't think there's only one way to have a SuiteApp. I see some are just bundles but some get more complex and they may require a guy to login to the account and install it and configure it manually, or a combination of both.

You need to have at least a SDN Select Account in order to have your SuiteApp listed on [www.suiteapp.com](http://www.suiteapp.com) . You get access to help on how to get it done and more. Once your SuiteApp is listed there people who are interested in your SuiteApp will contact you by filling a form.

More info here: http://www.netsuite.com/portal/common/pdf/ds-sdn.pdf

Also, if you want your SuiteApp to have the "Built for Netsuite" certification you need to check this out too: http://www.netsuite.com/portal/developers/built-for-netsuite.shtml

Comment: So we dont need any manifest files and deploy files???

Comment: I don't know, I would think so. Most likely yes if you want to certify your app as Built for Netsuite as they need to "ensure that SDN Partner solutions meet the same level of standards for security, data privacy and overall quality as the solutions offered by NetSuite".